# Не работают арифметические действия [qBasic]

Tags: qbasic

Здравствуйте, уважаемые кодеры.

В общем, решил написать простую игру на qBasic. Имеется такой код:

```
CLS
SCEEN 12
'...
num = 1
paste
paste
paste
SUB paste
'...
num = num+1
END SUB
```

Значение переменной num никак не хочет изменяться почему-то. В чём проблема? Я что-то не так делаю?

Спасибо огромное за любую помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Логично, потому что num в подпрограмме не имеет никакого отношения к num  в основной части.

исправленный вариант

```
DECLARE SUB paste(num)
CLS
'...
num = 1
paste(num)
paste(num)
paste(num)
PRINT num
SUB paste(num)
'...
num = num+1
END SUB
```

Можно сделать num глобальным (по всей видимости, используя common shared num), тогда Ваш код будет работать. Но я не насколько хорошо знаю qBasic.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, глобализация переменной num помогла.